# Which preposition should I use to point events in time {of/in/from}

Tags: prepositions

> The Mongols and Chinese both tried to conquer Vietnam at various points ( of / in / from ) second millennium.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Were all those "points" between 1001 and 2000? If so, you should use "*during the* second millennium".